# Alipay post URL when click on order submit

Tags: alipay

Which parameters are needed to build a Alipay post URL ?
Currently using https://openapi.alipaydev.com/gateway.do? as a test URL and service is service=create_forex_trade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to add following parameters
openapi is used for testing purpose while mapi.alipay.net is used for actual transaction purpose

https://openapi.alipaydev.com/gateway.do?_input_charset=utf-8

- body={ordernumber}
- currency={AUD}
- notify_url={notify_url}
- out_trade_no={}
- partner={partner_id}
- price=1395
- quantity=1
- return_url={return_url}
- service=trade_create_by_buyer
- sign={encryption_sign_key}
- sign_type=MD5